# On stability of bundles on projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a  projective surface in $\mathbb P^3$. Let $E$ be a rank $2$ bundle on $X$ which not slope stable (with respect to a fixed hyperplane class $H$).Then is the following statement true: There exists a line bundle $L$ contained in $E$ such that slope($L$)$ \geq $ slope ($E$)?

I don't see why this rank $2$ bundle is destabilized in terms of a line bundle and why not only in terms of zero dimensional sheaves?

Also in this context is the following calculation true: $H^0(\mathcal O_X(-k)^{\oplus 2}) = H^0(\mathcal O_X(-k)) \oplus H^0(\mathcal O_X(-k)) =0, \forall k \in \mathbb N$ ?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Assuming $X$ is reduced irreducible, a vector bundle can not contain zero dimensional sheaves.

Comment: @Mohan, sorry, I meant why not destabilization in terms of rank $1$ subsheaves which are not necessarily bundles

Comment: If $X$ is smooth, replace the destabilizing rank one subsheaf with its double dual, which also destabilizes and it is a line bundle. If $X$ is not smooth, I do not know.

Comment: @Mohan,Thank you very much for the answer.